# MVC3 razor: Add custom class to list with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a class setup like this

```
 public class MyCLass
 {
     //...
     public IList<MyInnerClass> InnerClass { get; set;}
 }

 public class MyInnerClass
 {
    public string A { get; set;}
    public string B { get; set;}
    //....
 }
```

in my cshtml form I can put it on all the page and post it back with something like

```
for(int i=0; i< Model.InnerClass.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.InnerClass[i].A);
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.InnerClass[i].B);
}
```

But now I need to have a button that can add a new instance of `MyInnerCLass`'s inputs below the existing ones dynamically with javascript and still bind everything back properly when I post the page. How would I do this? jQuery is preferred, but I can use anything that works

Comment: I would use a `foreach` for iterating over your list like so `foreach(var myClass in Model.InnerClass)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to wrap the each row of the for loop in some HTML tag, such as a div or tr, so that it can be referenced with jQuery. Then the you can use one of the generated rows as a template row. Indexes must be replaced with the appropriate value. Suppose you have this HTML output:

You can select the first row with jQuery and then clone it, replace the indexes using regex, then append the row:

```
var newRowIndex = x; // determine row index
var newRow = $("#rows .row").eq(0).clone(true);
newRow.find(":input").each(function() {
  var name = $(this).attr("name").replace(/\[\d+\]/, "[" + rowIndex.toString() + "]");
  var id = name.replace(/[.\]\[]/g, "_");
  $(this).attr("name", name);
  $(this).attr("id", id);
});
$("#rows").append(newRow);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out Phil Haacked blog [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx).  He posts almost everything about how the default model binder works with Lists.

As long as you used the `Non-Sequential Indices` method you can do what you want dynamically.